# How can I get rid of the "Restart now to finish the update" popup?

Tags: ota-update, developer-options

I have a Pixel 2 XL that I MUST keep on Android 10 for various reasons. *(Yes, I am aware of the implications of doing this. This is a device that I use for development tasks, I don't go to random websites on it, I don't install unknown apps, I never use it away from my trusted home WiFi network, etc.)* However Google seems hellbent on making me upgrade. Every few days I get a popup message (shown below) asking me to "restart now to finish the update." **I get this popup even though I have "automatic system updates" turned OFF in Developer Settings, and even though I have Google Play Services notifications turned OFF.** Is there any way to stop this message from appearing?

[image: this popup message]

Comment: On an un-rooted device as far as I know: No. If your development does not make use of GoogleSafetyNet I would recommend to unlock the bootloader. Then you can install any Android version you want between 8.0 and 11.0: https://developers.google.com/android/images#taimen upgrading and downgrading, both is possible. Usually this option is why people buy Google devices for development.